# DBIx::Class -- creating unique rows in sub-table

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

My (simplified) SQLite tables are like this:

```
create table customers (
    id              integer primary key autoincrement,
    contact_name    text,
    billaddr_id     integer references addresses(id)
);

create table addresses (
    id              integer primary key autoincrement,
    address         text
);
```

And here are the result classes (generated from the sql by dbicdump):

```
Test::DB::Schema::Result::Customer->table("customers");
Test::DB::Schema::Result::Customer->add_columns(
    "id", 
    { data_type => "integer", is_auto_increment => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
    "contact_name", 
    { data_type => "text", is_nullable => 1 },
    "billaddr_id", 
    { data_type => "integer", is_foreign_key => 1, is_nullable => 1 },
);
Test::DB::Schema::Result::Customer->set_primary_key("id");
Test::DB::Schema::Result::Address->table("addresses");
Test::DB::Schema::Result::Address->add_columns(
    "id", { data_type => "integer", is_auto_increment => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
    "address", { data_type => "text", is_nullable => 1 },
);
Test::DB::Schema::Result::Address->set_primary_key("id");
Test::DB::Schema::Result::Address->has_many(
    "customers", 
    "Test::DB::Schema::Result::Customer",
    { "foreign.billaddr_id" => "self.id" },
    { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
Test::DB::Schema::Result::Customer->belongs_to(
    "billaddr",
    "Test::DB::Schema::Result::Address",
    { id => "billaddr_id" },
    {
        is_deferrable => 0,
        join_type     => "LEFT",
        on_delete     => "NO ACTION",
        on_update     => "NO ACTION",
    },
);
```

This bit of code:

```
my $data = { 
    contact_name => 'Jim Customer',
    billaddr => {
        address => 'Address...',
    },  
};  
my $newcustomer = $c->schema->resultset('Customer')->create($data);
```

results in this database update:

```
SELECT me.id, me.address FROM addresses me WHERE ( ( me.address = ? ) ): 'Address...'
BEGIN WORK
SELECT me.id, me.address FROM addresses me WHERE ( ( me.address = ? ) ): 'Address...'
INSERT INTO addresses ( address ) VALUES ( ? ): 'Address...'
INSERT INTO partners ( billaddr_id, contact_name ) VALUES ( ?, ? ) : '10', 'Jim Customer'
COMMIT
```

Why does it do a select before the insert?  Because it's checking to see if an address with the same value of the 'address' column already exists.  If it does exist, the ID of that address is reused, like this:

```
SELECT me.id, me.address FROM addresses me WHERE ( ( me.address = ? ) ): 'Address...'
INSERT INTO partners ( billaddr_id, contact_name ) VALUES ( ?, ? ): '10', 'Another Customer with the same address'
```

But that's not what I want!  I want separate addresses for separate customers, even if they happen to live in the same place at the moment.

How can I make DBIx::Class create a new row in the addresses table every time?

Comment: You need to show us your result classes instead of the SQL statements used to create the tables. Why would you normalize your model if you always want a 1:1 relationship between customer and its address?

Comment: abraxxa -- Good question about normalization: I may in the end simplify the database structure.

But the general question remains: why does DBIx::Class assume that I want unique values in columns that I haven't asked to be unique?

Comment: abraxxa -- Having added the result classes to the question I see your point: they contain more detail than the original sql.  Address should 'have_one' customer rather than 'have_many'.  How do I tell dbicdump to do that?

Comment: It's generated from the database constraints which don't contain enough information to distinguish between the two. Dbicdump defaults to the more common use case which is a belongs_to/has_many relationship. Just change the generated result class to what you want and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to abraxxa's comments, I've been pointed in the right direction and have done more reading and testing with DBIx::Class:Schema.

Generating the table from the Schema classes, rather than the other way round, seems like the way to go, especially if it will make future upgrades to the database easier.

I've boiled the problem down to the following example code:

Test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Test::DB::Schema;
my $schema = Test::DB::Schema->connect(
    "dbi:SQLite:dbname=dbicsl_test.db", '', '', {}
);
$schema->deploy({ add_drop_table => 1 } , '.');
$schema->storage->debug(1);
my $data1 = { 
    text => 'Fred',
    table2 => {
        text => 'abc',
    }   
};
my $new1 = $schema->resultset('Table1')->create($data1);
my $data2 = { 
    text => 'Jim',
    table2 => {
        text => 'xyz',
    }   
};
my $new2 = $schema->resultset('Table1')->create($data2);
my $data3 = { 
    text => 'Emily',
    table2 => {
        text => 'abc',
    }   
};
my $new3 = $schema->resultset('Table1')->create($data3);
```

Test::DB::Schema::Result::Table1.pm:

```
package Test::DB::Schema::Result::Table1;
use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("table1");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  { data_type => "integer", is_auto_increment => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
  "text",
  { data_type => "text", is_nullable => 1 },
  "table2_id",
  { data_type => "integer", is_foreign_key => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");
__PACKAGE__->has_one(
    table2 =>
    "Test::DB::Schema::Result::Table2",
    { 'foreign.id' => 'self.table2_id' },
);
1;
```

Test::DB::Schema::Result::Table2:

```
package Test::DB::Schema::Result::Table2;
use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("table2");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  { data_type => "integer", is_auto_increment => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
  "text",
  { data_type => "text", is_nullable => 0 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");
1;
```

And here's the output:

```
SELECT me.id, me.text FROM table2 me WHERE ( me.text = ? ): 'abc'
BEGIN WORK
SELECT me.id, me.text FROM table2 me WHERE ( me.text = ? ): 'abc'
INSERT INTO table2 ( text) VALUES ( ? ): 'abc'
INSERT INTO table1 ( table2_id, text) VALUES ( ?, ? ): '1', 'Fred'
COMMIT
SELECT me.id, me.text FROM table2 me WHERE ( me.text = ? ): 'xyz'
BEGIN WORK
SELECT me.id, me.text FROM table2 me WHERE ( me.text = ? ): 'xyz'
INSERT INTO table2 ( text) VALUES ( ? ): 'xyz'
INSERT INTO table1 ( table2_id, text) VALUES ( ?, ? ): '2', 'Jim'
COMMIT
SELECT me.id, me.text FROM table2 me WHERE ( me.text = ? ): 'abc'
INSERT INTO table1 ( table2_id, text) VALUES ( ?, ? ): '1', 'Emily'
```

So the database now looks like

```
table1.id  table1.text table1.table2_id
1          Fred        1
2          Jim         2
3          Emily       1

table2.id  table2.text
1          abc
2          xyz
```

whereas I expected / hoped for:

```
table1.id  table1.text table1.table2_id
1          Fred        1
2          Jim         2
3          Emily       3

table2.id  table2.text
1          abc
2          xyz
3          abc
```

Why does it reuse 1/abc when I haven't told it to make the table2.text column unique?

Comment: Perhaps I should have edited the question instead of supplying an 'answer'. I still haven't solved this problem, although the need for an answer is no longer urgent.